# Using radio FormElement in a drupal 8 ListBuilder

Tags: 8, entities, forms, configuration

I made a [custom configuration entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityBase.php/class/ConfigEntityBase/8.8.x), and I'm trying to set up radio buttons in the [listBuilder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityListBuilder.php/class/ConfigEntityListBuilder/8.2.x). [This is done in the core module language](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21LanguageListBuilder.php/class/LanguageListBuilder/8.8.x) without any problems, but when I try to do the same trick with my custom entity I can't get any radio button. Instead the attributes are rendered in the html element.

```php
    public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
      $row['label'] = $entity->label();
      $row['default'] = [
        '#type' => 'radio',
        '#parents' => ['site_default_language'],
        '#title' => t('Set @title as default', ['@title' => $entity->label()]),
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#return_value' => $entity->id(),
        '#id' => 'edit-site-default-language-' . $entity->id(),
      ];
      // Mark the right language as default in the form.
      if ($entity->id() == $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId()) {
        $row['default']['#default_value'] = $entity->id();
      }
      return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
    }
```

Then I get this html element as a result without any errors in the logs:

```html
<td #type="radio" #parents="active_scsp_server" 
#title="..." #title_display="invisible" 
#return_value="pre" #id="edit-active-scsp-server-pre" #default_value="pre">
</td>
```

Comment: Are you extending DraggableListBuilder as well? This thing is actually a Form in disguise.

Comment: Yes, I am extending DraggableListBuilder, mimicking a big part of LanguageListBuilder. But, the problem is that I am not getting any form... I already tryed to reinstall the entity, clearing cache and so on...

Comment: Maybe try `$row['default'][$entity->id()] = [...]`. And can't the `#default_value` just be `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `NULL`? Can it be an ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the DraggableListBuilder work, the entity need to have a `weigth` key defined. Otherwise it will fail silently.